# Scaling (or Adding) Two Images in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, imageview, android-imageview

I have an activity where I take user input. Then, I have an activity that displays a ImageView (ImageOne) the size of the screen. To do this I am scaling it centerCrop. However, based on user input there will be another, smaller image (ImageTwo which will vary based on input) on top of ImageOne. Is there a way to scale ImageTwo based on the scaling of the ImageOne, or a way to add the two images and then scale them in the same ImageView.

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

save the dimension in res>values>dimens and use same dimens like getResources().getDimension(R.id.yourDimension) 
for scaling both images

//in dimens file

```
 <integer name="yourDimension">20</integer>
```

Comment: I am using picaso so my code is like this Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.yourImageResource).resize(getResources().getDimension(R.id.yourDimension), getResources().getDimension(R.id.yourDimension)).centerCrop().into(R.id.yourImageView);

Answer (score 1):

> However, based on user input I need to add another, smaller image
>   (ImageTwo) on top of ImageOne.

Why not try a `FrameLayout` in which `ImageOne` will be at a lower level and `ImageTwo` at a higher level? Keep `ImageTwo` hidden and when user gives you the go ahead, just make it visible. Since it is a smaller image, your lower `ImageOne` will be seen.

If you really have to replace the pixels of `ImageOne` when user provides the input, you have a bit of work to do. You will first have to get the `Bitmap` of `ImageOne` and then, after doing some mathemagics, use `replacePixels()` to replace the pixels with those of `ImageTwo`. It depends upon your requirement, really.

Resource:
[FrameLayout](http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2013/10/10/framelayout-your-best-ui-friend/)